# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Using vitejs and redux-mock-store

Tags: reactjs, vite, redux-mock-store

Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
❯ dispatch node_modules/redux-mock-store/lib/index.js:41:19

```
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetch({ url }))
        ^
    }, [url, reload])
```

Using vitejs and redux-mock-store it should mock redux dispatch function

Answer (score 0):

I forgot add middleware with redux-thunk.

`import thunk from 'redux-thunk'`

//...

`const middlewares = [thunk]`

`const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);`

//...

ref: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store#asynchronous-actions